# Responsive Div Re-alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, alignment, media-queries

Working on a mobile first approach and have encountered a strange re-alignment issue while expanding from mobile (480) to tablet view (768px).

The final layout is supposed to look like this:
[image]

However, I see this:
[image]

I understand that this is a CSS display issue, I can get Display: inline-block to work for the text segment to align with the album artwork (I have to reduce the width of the div though), but I cannot get the Display: inline-block to apply to the third div and to get it to align on the right hand side of the text box. Here's the HTML (removed unnecessary code for this question). The three relevant classes are'album-artwork', 'info-bar-container' and 'dig-box' (the lightning bolt). What is the best way to go about fixing this problem?

Thank you for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

    <title>UNCVRD</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Font awesome icons -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shiv and REspond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
        <!-- Music Feed -->
        <section id="music-feed">
            <div class="song-container">
                <div class="album-artwork">
                    <img class="sc-artwork" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000182929734-focihg-t500x500.jpg">
                    <div class="album-dark-overlay">
                        <div class="ranking-triangle"></div>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info-bar-container">
                    <div class="info-bar">
                        <div class="info-bar-text">
                            <div class="artist-name">Echos - Gold</div>
                            <div class="curator-name">Curated by <a class="curator-link" href="">UNCVRD</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dig-box">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-bolt balanced"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </section>

    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS stylesheet!

```
/* Reference Palette

Background: #dedede
Grey font: #b9b9b9
*/


/* ==== General ==== */

html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #dedede;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* ==== Navigation Bar ==== */

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;
    margin: 13px 0 0 16px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -53.5px !important;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    color: black;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: black;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -7.5px;
}
.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 3.25px;
}

/* ==== FEED ==== */

#feed {
    width: 480px;
    margin: auto;
}

/* ==== Playlist Mode ==== */

.playlist-header {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.playlist-select {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 260px;
}
.discovery-mode {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    min-width: 130px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.playlist-choice {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 26px;
}

/* ==== Music Feed ==== */

#music-feed {
    margin-top: 16px;
    width: 448px;
}
.song-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.song-container:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 82px;
}
.album-artwork {
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.sc-artwork {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.info-bar-container {
    display: flex;
}
.album-dark-overlay {
    /*    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 77.5px;
    color: #dedede;
}
.ranking-triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 38px 38px 0 0;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.ranking {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 38px;
    text-align: left;
}
.info-bar {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 484px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: white;
    display: table;
}
.dig-box {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 65px;
    max-height: 65px;
}
.ion-ios-bolt {
    color: #dedede;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.ion-ios-bolt:hover {
    color: black;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition: .5s;
}
.ion-ios-play {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

.ion-ios-play:hover {
    color: #b9b9b9;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition: .5s;
}
.info-bar-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#music-feed .artist-name {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
#music-feed .curator-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #b9b9b9;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
.curator-link {
    color: black;
}
.curator-link:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ==== Progress Bar ==== */

#progress-bar-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
}
#progress-bar-container .container-fluid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 6px;
}
.progress-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #b9b9b9;
    position: fixed;
}
.progress-bar {
    width: 40%;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* ==== Bottom Music Bar ==== */

#music-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#music-bar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
}
.music-control-container {
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-flex;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#music-bar .ion-ios-rewind {
    margin-left: 16px;
}
#music-bar .ion-pause {
    margin: 0 12px;
}
#music-bar .ion-ios-fastforward {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#music-bar .album-artwork {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.music-control-container img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#music-bar .song-name {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/* ==== Custom Media Queries ==== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #feed {
        width: 768px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #music-feed {
        width: 736px;
    }
    .song-container {
        height: 160px;

    }
    .album-artwork {
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        margin-right: -4px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .info-bar-container {
        width: 576px;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    .info-bar {
        max-width: 576px;
        height: 160px;

    }
    .dig-box {
        width: 10%;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 160px;
        max-height: 160px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set a width on your #music-feed which appears to be too thin to hold all the items, causing them to drop down to the next lines. Also your div.dig-box isn't set to "display: inline-block" so by default wants to occupy a line by itself.

From there onwards you have a bit more work to do but hope this helps.